# Retrieve value of annotation for an enum

Tags: java, enums, java-annotations

I have these annotations:

```or-tag-here
@interface NotNull {
  boolean value() default false;
}

@interface Type {
  Class<?> value();
}
```

and then I use them with an enum:

```java
public enum KeyMap implements IMapEnum {

  @Type(Integer.class)
  @NotNull
  USER_ID("user_id", "userId"),

  @NotNull
  USER_HANDLE("user_handle", "userHandle"),

  @NotNull
  USER_EMAIL("user_email", "userEmail");

  private String key;
  private String value;

  KeyMap(String k, String v) {
    this.key = k;
    this.value = v;
  }

  @Override
  public String getKey() {
    return this.key;
  }

  @Override
  public String getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }

}
```

my question is - how do I retrieve the value of the annotation for each instance of the enum?  The interface being implemented is simple and is not really part of the question:

```java
public interface IMapEnum {
  String getKey();
  String getValue();
}
```

but maybe someone can show how to retrieve the annotations in either `getKey` or `getValue` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add [runtime retention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#RUNTIME) to your annotations so they can be read using reflection:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface NotNull {
    boolean value() default false;
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Type {
    Class<?> value();
}
```

Then you can use reflection to obtain the annotations treating enum constant as a class field:

```
Field field = KeyMap.class.getField(KeyMap.USER_ID.name());
Annotation[] annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(annotations));
```

will print:

```
[@Type(value=java.lang.Integer.class), @NotNull(value=false)]
```

Comment: Nice thanks a ton, will accept it tomorrow..quick question - how could I store the annotations in a map?  Something like `Map.of(@Type, Integer.class, @NotNull, false)`...but how exactly?

Comment: @rakim apologies but I do not understand the `Map` question. You could create `Map<java.lang.annotation.Annotation, ?>` but I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: If I want to see if an object has a certain annotation? I could store the annotations in a map on the object, and then look up the annotation as a key in the map, right?

Comment: please see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54661961/store-annotations-in-a-map-and-look-them-up-later the reason is I only want to use reflection once, I don't want to keep using reflection look up the annotations everytime