# Store Annotations in a map, and look them up later

Tags: java, annotations

is there a way to store the annotations for object in a map?

```
class HasFieldsWithAnnotations {

    Set<Annotation> annots = new HashSet<>();

    public boolean hasAnnotation(Annotation a) {
      return this.annots.contains(a);
    }
}
```

and then we instantiate it:

```
var c = new HasFieldsWithAnnotations();
c.hasAnnotation(?);
```

how would I pass an annotation to the hasAnnotation method?

Comment: You can't directly instantiate an annotation, it is constructed using a java proxy factory. Better question; what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: If I want to see if something has an annotation without using reflection I store the Annotation in a map, for use later. But how to look it up in the map later?

Comment: You probably want to check using the `Class` object, not an `Annotation` instance. Try `hasAnnotation(Class<? Annotation> annotation)` and then you can pass in: `c.hasAnnotation(NotNull.class)`. You still have to use reflection the first time, but you can cache the result of `getDeclaredAnnotations` in a map or set for quick access on subsequent calls.

Comment: Looks like XY Problem to me

Comment: I updated the OP to make it clearer, I just want to store the annotations in a set, and later on see if an object has an annotation - the motivation is that I don't want to have to use reflection each time I check for presence of annotation